# ¿Como insertar en un árbol binario nivel por nivel?

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

Resulta que estoy creando un programa en c++ que construye un heap con la prioridad máxima, la idea es que los nodos se inserten de izquierda a derecha y de arriba hacia abajo tal y como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La estructura del nodo es como sigue:

```
template <class T>
struct nodoprior{
   T info;
   int prior;
   nodoprior *izq,*der,*padre;
 };
```

Lo primordial es hacer que el programa me inserte nivel por nivel y es esto lo que tengo a continuación:

```
template <class T>
nodoprior<T> *ColaPrioridad<T>::encontrarPosInsertar(nodoprior<T> *nod){
nodoprior<T> *aux;
if(nod==NULL) return NULL;

//crea una cola vacia para el recorido por niveles
cola<nodoprior<T> *> q;

//inserte la raiz e inicialice la altura
q.InsCola(nod);

while(q.ColaVacia()==false){


    aux= q.AtenderCola();


    //inserte hijo de la izq
    if(aux->izq!=NULL) {

        q.InsCola(aux->izq);
    }

    //inserte hijo de la der
    if(aux->der!=NULL) {
        q.InsCola(aux->der);
    }

}
return aux;


}
```

El método anterior lo modifiqué del recorrido por niveles, yo esperaría que me retornara la dirección de memoria donde debe ser insertado el nuevo nodo.

```
template <class T>
void ColaPrioridad<T>::insertar(T dato, int prioridad){
nodoprior<T> *nuevo;
nodoprior<T> *aux;
T copiadato;
int copiaprior;
nuevo= new nodoprior<T>;
nuevo->info=dato;
nuevo->der=NULL;
nuevo->izq=NULL;
nuevo->padre=NULL;
nuevo->prior=prioridad;
if(raiz==NULL){

    raiz=nuevo;


}
else{

    //encuentra la pos donde debe ser insertado el nuevo nodo
    aux=encontrarPosInsertar(raiz);
    T datoaux=aux->info;
    //el padre es aquel nodo encontrado
    nuevo->padre=aux;
    //se le da prioridad a la izquierda para insertar
    if(aux->izq==NULL){
        aux->izq=nuevo;

    }
    else {
        aux->der=nuevo;

    }
```

Esta función se encarga de insertar el correspondiente nodo, sin embargo el algoritmo lo que está haciendo es retornando siempre la posición izquierda de cada nodo y por ende no me está funcionando como debe, y ese error viene de la función encontrarPosInsertar, ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar esto, u otra alternativa más sencilla sin arreglos?

Answer (score 1):

En un árbol, se presupone que el nodo izquierdo va a tener un valor inferior al del nodo actual mientras que el valor en el nodo derecho va a ser superior.

Si insertamos la secuencia 4,2,5,1,3, el árbol resultante (sin reorganización) debería ser:

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3
```

Esto choca con la lógica que has implementado:

```
//se le da prioridad a la izquierda para insertar
if(aux->izq==NULL){
    aux->izq=nuevo;

}
else {
    aux->der=nuevo;

}
```

Ya que lo que tendría que suceder es que la posición vendría determinada por el valor del nodo con respecto a su padre.

Si lo que deseas es que el nodo cumpla ciertas características... como que el número de hijos en cada rama tienda a ser similar y detalles por el estilo entonces tendrías que aplicar transformaciones al árbol siempre después de haber insertado el nuevo nodo... hay abundante documentación al respecto en Internet y es un tema demasiado extenso para tratarlo en una única respuesta.

Si el árbol no va a estar ordenado de ninguna forma entonces no tiene sentido crear una estructura en árbol porque encontrar información en el mismo va a implicar iterar por todos los nodos hasta dar con el elemento buscado... en este caso usando `std::vector` vas a invertir menos tiempo en encontrar los elementos.

**EDITO:**

Si lo que deseas es disponer de una estructura en la que los nodos con menor valor se ubiquen en las primeras posiciones lo que necesitas es `std::set` (si no puede haber duplicados) o `std::multiset` (si puede haberlos).

Ambos contenedores son ordenados, lo que te garantiza que los elementos van a estar siempre organizados.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si en parte tienes razón, el arbol binario cumple esas cualidades, pero resulta que en el heap, no importa el orden de los elementos, sino la prioridad que éste tenga, siempre se cumple que el padre tiene mayor prioridad que sus hijos, por ejemplo tomando la prioridad como numeros, el padre tiene mayor numero que el hijo y así. Pero la inserción siempre se hace de la misma forma en la que puse en la imágen.

Comment: @DanielEstebanLadinoTorres Entonces no necesitas un árbol sino `std::set` o `std::multiset`. Con cualquiera de estos dos contenedores te garantizas que los elementos van a estar ordenados... al crear el contenedor puedes especificar una función que permita comparar los diferentes elementos en función de tus necesidades (por ejemplo la prioridad), o bien puedes sobrecargar el operador menor que de la estructura para que el contenedor sepa organizar los elementos.

Comment: pues podría ser, sin embargo se me exige que lo haga de ésta forma...

Comment: @eferion `std::set`, etc son ineficientes para implementar colas de prioridad, porque no necesitas que el árbol esté ordenado, solo que accedas, de la manera más rápida posible, al elemento de menor valor.

Answer (score 0):

Los `heap`s (en español, árboles parcialmente ordenados, o montículos), como muestras en tu gráfico, son completos, para que tengan la menor profundidad posible (y así, reordenar el árbol, que usualmente es reordenar la rama en la que insertaste al hacer `push`, o del hijo que seleccionaste al hacer `pop`), sea lo más rápida posible.

Al ser completos, conocer al padre o al hijo de un nodo se puede hacer con operaciones matemáticas sencillas que dependen de la profundidad del nodo, y al ser completo (y por tanto, no desperdiciar memoria), y poderse recorrer numéricamente, se puede implementar en un `std::vector`.

C++ tiene las funciones [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`std::pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap), y [`std::push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap), que modifican un contenedor para tratarlo como un montículo (es decir, reordenan los elementos para que sea un árbol parcialmente ordenado y completo).

```
std::vector<int> v{5, 1, 8, 2, 4};
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
int min = std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

El problema es que si luego, accidentalmente, modificas `v` (por ejemplo `v[3] = 9;`), el vector deja de ser un *heap* y cuando llames a `std::pop_heap` o `std::push_heap`, lo que obtendrás serán resultados diferentes a los esperados.

Por eso también C++ dispone de [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), que hace lo mismo, pero el contenedor es interno.